# Converting objective c method to c# stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f%@"

Tags: c#, objective-c, nstimeinterval, stringwithformat

Okay, I am working on converting some objective c code to c# here is what I have.

```
NSTimeInterval now = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];


NSData * formattedstring= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f%@", string1, now, string2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So for I have created a helper class and I have this:

```
var authTime = GetTimeIntervalSince1970(DateTime.Now);

var authDataString = String.Format("{0}{1}{2]",username, authTime, password);
```

So, my question is the "%.0f" and the "dataUsingEncoding:NSTimeInterval".  I know the first part has something to do with formatting the "now" parameter, what do I need to do to make sure I'm doing the same thing in c#, and can someone explain this to me in detail or direct me to an article/blog I should read?

Thanks!

Update: Okay guys I messed up, I'm sorry I copied and pasted wrong which is party of my confusion. the dataUsingEncoding:NSTimeInterval should read: dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. So I have fixed the post.

Comment: What is the expected output for the date?

Comment: Doesn't `dataUsingEncoding:NSTimeInterval` throw error on your screen?

Comment: The `%@` formatting  code causes an Objective-C object to be displayed.  For NSStrings it just prints the string characters.  The `%.0f` code is to format a floating-point number (in non-exponential format).  The format indicates that the number is to be printed without any fractional part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your Objective-C code consists of two parts:

```
NSString *tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.0f%@", string1, now, string2];
```

and

```
NSData *formattedstring = [tmp dataUsingEncoding:NSTimeInterval];
```

The first part generates a string. `NSTimeInterval` is `typedef`ed to `double`, so `%.0f` basically format the floor of `now` (e.g. from `3.1415926` to `@"3"`). So, assuming your `GetTimeIntervalSince1970` returns a floating number, the equivalent in C# is

```
string tmp = string.Format("{0}{1:F0}{2}", username, authTime, password);
```

The second part, however, is confusing. `dataUsingEncoding:` takes an `NSStringEncoding` argument, but `NSTimeInterval` is **not** one of the available [built-in constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). As a matter of fact, this most likely shouldn't even compile because `NSTimeInterval` is an `typedef`, and can't be converted (implicitly) to an integer. I think `NSData` is roughly equivalent to `System.Byte[]` in C#, but whether you need to convert the string depends on your specific need.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer, it was explained very well. :D  I think I've got it figured out now with your and everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var authDataString = String.Format("{0}{1:F0}{2}",username, authTime, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For the "%.0f", you can read Apple's documents (It's just ANSI C's `printf` format plus %@ for any object):

   - [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)
   - [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)
2. As for `dataUsingEncoding:NSTimeInterval`，I don't think the original Objective-C code is correct. `NSString`'s `dataUsingEncoding:` method's signature is like this:

   `- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

   Possible values for `encoding` are defined here: [String Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringEncoding), passing `NSTimeInterval` as `NSStringEncoding` makes no sense here.